# Como alterar o nome de uma variável categórica no eixo x de um boxplot?

Tags: r

Estou analisando dados do Enem para comparar desempenho médio entre escolas publicas e particulares. O tipo de escola pública leva "2" na base e "3" quando particular. Utilizei o seguinte código para plotagem:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
boxplot(NOTA_CH ~ TP_ESCOLA, escolas, xlab = "Tipo de Escola", ylab = "Nota Ciências Humanas", col = "grey", show.legend = T)
boxplot(NOTA_CN ~ TP_ESCOLA, escolas, xlab = "Tipo de Escola", ylab = "Nota Ciências Naturais", col = "grey")
boxplot(NOTA_MT ~ TP_ESCOLA, escolas, xlab = "Tipo de Escola", ylab = "Nota Matemática", col = "grey")
boxplot(NOTA_LC ~ TP_ESCOLA, escolas, xlab = "Tipo de Escola", ylab = "Nota Linguangens", col = "grey")
boxplot(NOTA_REDACAO ~ TP_ESCOLA, escolas, xlab = "Tipo de Escola", ylab = "Nota Redação", col = "grey")
```

O resultado foi este:

:[image: descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para alterar no gráfico o "2" e "3" para "Publica" e "Privada"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

seu_DataFrame['Tipo de Escola'] = seu_DataFrame['Tipo de Escola'].map({2: 'Pública', 3: 'Privada'})

Espero que ajude!